# Transitions not working with a router in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I'm making a SwiftUI based app.

I had embedded in the main hierarchy a router to manage app navigation. At the beginning this was working good but then I added a second level of router and transitions got broken and stop working.

Actually, the navigation in both routers are working well but cannot make it work with transitions.

App root goes to this file:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if authRouter.isFirstLaunch {
            AuthView()
        } else if sessionState.launchListeningCompleted || sessionState.user != nil || sessionState.error != nil {
            Home()
        } else {
            ZStack {
                Image("Icon")
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    ActivityIndicatorUI(animating: .constant(true), style: .medium)
                        .padding(.bottom)
                    Image("Launcher")
                        .padding(.bottom, 95.0)
                        .padding(.top)
                }
            }
        }
    }.onAppear(perform: isFirstLaunch)
}
```

Essentially, if is first time app is launching, it will go to AuthView file which is a router like this:

```
struct AuthView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var authRouter: AuthRouter

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if authRouter.viewName == AuthViews.Onboarding {
            Onboarding()
        } else if authRouter.viewName == AuthViews.SignIn {
            SignIn()
                .transition(.scale)
        } else if authRouter.viewName == AuthViews.SignUp {
            SignUp()
                .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        } else if authRouter.viewName == AuthViews.ForgotPassword {
            ForgotPassword()
                .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        }
    }
}
```

}

Those transitions are not working. At the beginning this was the first router I added and it was working. Then at the second level it stopped working.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add animation to parent container

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if authRouter.viewName == AuthViews.Onboarding {
            Onboarding()
        } else if authRouter.viewName == AuthViews.SignIn {
            SignIn()
                .transition(.scale)
        } else if authRouter.viewName == AuthViews.SignUp {
            SignUp()
                .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        } else if authRouter.viewName == AuthViews.ForgotPassword {
            ForgotPassword()
                .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        }
    }.animation(.default)     // << here !! (any animation you like)
}
```

and make sure that `authRouter.viewName` is always updated on `DispatchQueue.main`.

Comment: Do you know why it was working without .animation() at the beginning or when to use it and when avoid it? Thanks. The suggestion is working perfect.